# Function for accessing regression output

Tags: r

I just wrote this function for personal use only while working on a specific data project. I would be grateful for any feedback!

```
get.coef1 <- function(x) {
  x <- as.character(x)
  m.names <- paste("fit", x, letters[1:3], sep="")
  models3 <- matrix(numeric(12L), 3, 4)
  for (i in 1:3) {
    models3[i, ] <- summary(get(m.names[i]))$coefficients[2,]
  }
  return(models3)
}
```

Data to reproduce function above:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- x^2/4
z <- rnorm(100)+y/100
w <- rnorm(100)
```

Edit1:
And three fitted regressions:

```
fit3a <- lm(y ~ x)
fit3b <- lm(y ~ x + z)
fit3c <- lm(y ~ x + z + w)
```

Whose coefficients on `x` I want to access via`get.coef1(3)`.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some great answers.

Comment: Welcome. Could you show us what input you use when making a call to the function? Also, does the function not assume you have `fit{something}{a,b,c}` objects in your environment? Can you show how these were built? Thank you.

Comment: The function assumes I have fit 3 regressions. I just added an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has several problematic assumptions for the object names in the environment (`get()`) and the number of objects (fixed length in the `for` loop).

In base R it would be more idiomatic and flexible to use some function from the *apply family, which operate on a list of objects, e.g.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(fit3a, fit3b, fit3c),
                      function(x) summary(x)$coefficients["x", ]))
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
[1,]  0.01512    0.02927  0.5164   0.6067
[2,]  0.01530    0.02985  0.5127   0.6093
[3,]  0.01732    0.02899  0.5975   0.5516

t(sapply(list(fit3a, fit3b, fit3c),
         function(x) summary(x)$coefficients["x", ]))
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
[1,]  0.01512    0.02927  0.5164   0.6067
[2,]  0.01530    0.02985  0.5127   0.6093
[3,]  0.01732    0.02899  0.5975   0.5516
```

Output of `get.coef1(3)` (with `set.seed(1)`):

```
        [,1]    [,2]   [,3]   [,4]
[1,] 0.01512 0.02927 0.5164 0.6067
[2,] 0.01530 0.02985 0.5127 0.6093
[3,] 0.01732 0.02899 0.5975 0.5516
```